# How to add scroll event in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Version 2.2.

I have tried like this but not working.

```
`componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).addEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.table).removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenScrollEvent);
}

listenScrollEvent() {
    console.log('Scroll event detected!');
}

render() {
    return (
        <table ref="table">
           [...]
        </table>
    )
}`
```

Please suggest me correct way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen for event scroll on parent of table... like window or an element that will have the scrollbar